# Does elementRef.nativeElement.remove() have any negative effects on the browser?

Tags: angular, dom

I'm setting a timeout to destroy a component on Angular 2 that may be destroyed before the timeout is called. The timeout is called either way and it does a .remove() on the native element of the component (even though it is no longer in the dom).

If the element is destroyed and the timeout executes to remove the already destroyed component are there any negative side affects that are not visible?

```
export class AnimationCloserComponent {
    public queryParams$;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private elementRef:ElementRef,
        private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {}    

    ngOnInit() {
        /* Will look for routing instructions with QueryParams to route and close this component. These instructions may sometimes not be available.. */
        this.queryParams$ = this.activatedRoute
            .queryParamMap 
            .map(params => {
                    let closeOutletName = params.get('closeOutlet') || null;
                    if (closeOutletName != null) {
                        this.router.navigate(['', { outlets: { [closeOutletName]: null }}]);
                    }
                    return params.get('closeOutlet') || null;
                }
            );

        /* This is meant to destroy the component if the router could not route away from it. */
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.elementRef.nativeElement.remove();
        }, 1500);
    }    
}
```

I really wanted to ask if just doing this is ok before I make this a practice. (already clarified below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is almost never OK to remove native DOM elements without Angular knowing about it. Angular keeps all component related nodes (including child components) in the abstraction called [View](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-why-you-will-not-find-components-inside-angular-bdaf204d955c#4e19). Nodes in the view point to DOM elements. Consider the following setup:

```
ComponentA
   ComponentB
```

the view hierarchy will be something like this:

```
ComponentAView
    ElementNode('<b-comp>', document.createElement('<b-comp>'))
        ComponentBView
           ...
    ComponentClassNode(new ComponentB());
```

If you remove the first element `<b-comp>` from the DOM Angular knows nothing about it. It will continue thinking that there's a child component available.

This may result in the unexpected consequences like Angular reporting a child component in the `@ViewChildren` while you have removed it from the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for this. What should I do to remove the component safely?

Comment: @Jonathan002, can you add more details why you need that?

Comment: I have a delicate setup in the project for animation that relies on an empty component that is loaded dynamically. It is hard to keep track of where this component will appear since it is frequently used. I'm able to remove it through various methods e.g. routing. However there may be cases where knowing where to route is not available. I have the timeout function attempt to remove the component just in case routing is not possible.

Comment: @Jonathan002, pretty confusing, where do you call `setTimeout`?

Comment: I call it at ngOnInit of the component. The component does two things in ngOnInit() route listening and timeout removal. It tries to listen for routing instructions (but will do nothing if it does not receive any) and has a timeout to remove it that is always called no matter what.

Comment: @Jonathan002, please add the code with explanation to the question details

Comment: @Jonathan002, sorry, too little info to give credible advice. I answered your question regarding the component destruction. Maybe you should create another question specific to how to handle component destruction where you outline the concept. The community will be more helpful then just me

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I'll mark this as the correct answer since we are getting into two sepparate questions. : )

Comment: @Jonathan002, yeah, thanks) post a link here if you create another related question